# Extract correct counter value of a reference

Tags: cross-referencing, counters, xstring

Somewhere in my document there is a theorem labelled `theoremA` that has the number `2.21`. Later, I want to set another counter to that specific number `21`.

First, I tried `\setcounterref{newcounter}{reference}` which does not work as I expected it to: `theoremA` has the counter value `2.21` and `\setcounterref` sets `newcounter` to `2` instead of `21`.

To fix this, I tried `\setcounter{theorem}{\StrBehind{\getrefnumber{orbitcomeagre}}{.}}` which yields the error `Missing number, treated as zero`even though `\StrBehind{\getrefnumber{orbitcomeagre}}{.}`has the correct value of `21`.

Does anyone have any suggestions how I can fix this?

Comment: There's an important distinction to make:`\thetheorem` produces "2.21", but `\value{theorem}` produces "21".

Comment: @Mico: True, but this is only correct (after and) close to the particular theorem, not as a reference in a completely different place in the document where other theorems may precede it.

Comment: @Werner - Correct. The upshot, in my view, is that if the OP wants to store the value of the theorem counter for later re-use, it's most straightforward to do so by using `\value{theorem}` immediately after the theorem in question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing an important complication, but I think all you need to do is (a) define a "scratch" counter variable named, say, `scratchcounter`, in the preamble and (b) use an instruction such as

```
\setcounter{scratchcounter}{\value{theorem}}
```

immediately after the theorem in question to store the number of the theorem (minus the "prefix") in the counter named `scratchcounter`. Its value may be accessed elsewhere in the document via `\thescratchcounter`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm} % or: "\usepackage{ntheorem}"
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\newcounter{scratchcounter} % define the scratch counter

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{2}   % just for this example
\setcounter{theorem}{20}

\begin{theorem}[Pythagoras] \label{thm:pyth}
$a^2+b^2=c^2$.
\end{theorem}
\setcounter{scratchcounter}{\value{theorem}} % Store value of 'theorem' counter

\bigskip\noindent
Later on \dots\ the value of the ``scratch'' counter is \thescratchcounter.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The idea of `\StrBehind` is good, but you have to use it in a different way.

```
\StrBehind{\getrefnumber{orbitcomeagre}}{.}[\orbitcomeagrenumber]
\setcounter{theorem}{0\orbitcomeagrenumber}
```

The `0` is for avoiding issues when the reference is not yet defined and `\StrBehind` would output nothing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring,refcount}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newcounter{mycount}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{1}
\section{A section}

\setcounter{theorem}{20}

\begin{theorem}\label{orbitcomeagre}
A theorem.
\end{theorem}

See Theorem~\ref{orbitcomeagre}.

\StrBehind{\getrefnumber{orbitcomeagre}}{.}[\orbitcomeagrenumber]
\setcounter{mycount}{0\orbitcomeagrenumber}

See Theorem~\themycount.

\end{document}
```

[image]

An “abstract” version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring,refcount}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\newcounter{mycount}

\newcommand{\setcountertoref}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \StrBehind{\getrefnumber{#2}}{.}[\setcountertoreftemp]%
  \setcounter{#1}{0\setcountertoreftemp}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{1}
\section{A section}

\setcounter{theorem}{20}

\begin{theorem}\label{orbitcomeagre}
A theorem.
\end{theorem}

See Theorem~\ref{orbitcomeagre}.

\setcountertoref{mycount}{orbitcomeagre}

See Theorem~\themycount.

\end{document}‎
```

Answer (score 3):

The following solution implements `\extractthmnum{<cnt>}{<ref>}` in a similar way to [`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount)'s `\setcounterref`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newcounter{mycount}

\makeatletter
\def\@extractthmnum#1.#2{#2}
\newcommand{\extractthmnum}[2]{% \extractthmnum{<cnt>}{<ref>}
  \setcounter{#1}{0}% Default
  \ifcsname r@#2\endcsname
    \edef\@tempa{\csname r@#2\endcsname}% Extract complete reference
    \edef\@tempa{\expandafter\@firstoftwo\@tempa}% Extract number
    \setcounter{#1}{\expandafter\@extractthmnum\@tempa}% Strip number
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{1}
\section{A section}

\setcounter{theorem}{20}
\begin{theorem}\label{thm:theorem}
A theorem.
\end{theorem}

See Theorem~\ref{thm:theorem}.

\extractthmnum{mycount}{thm:theorem}%
See Theorem~\themycount.

‎\end{document}‎
```