# Countinuations of examples

Tags: counters, amsthm

In the accepted answer of the following question: [Continuing an earlier theorem-like environment with amsthm & thmtools](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430675/continuing-an-earlier-theorem-like-environment-with-amsthm-thmtools), two methods are described for continuation of examples.

I would like to use the first method to do the same thing where all examples use the following environment:

```
\newtheorem{examp}{Example}[section]        
\newenvironment{exa}[1][]{%
        \begin{adjustwidth}{3mm}{3mm}
            \needspace{2\baselineskip}
            \rule{\textwidth-6mm}{.2mm} 
            \begin{examp}[#1]}{
            \end{examp}
            \vspace*{-2mm} 
            \noindent
            \rule{\columnwidth-6mm}{.2mm}  
        \end{adjustwidth}%
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that it is possible. Adding the following after my original definitions solves the problem:

```
    \newtheorem*{excont}{Example \continuation}
    \newcommand{\continuation}{??}
    \newenvironment{contexa}[1]{
    \begin{adjustwidth}{3mm}{3mm}
        \needspace{2\baselineskip}
        \rule{\textwidth-6mm}{.2mm} 
        \renewcommand{\continuation}{\ref{#1}}\excont[continued]}
        {{\endexcont}
        \vspace*{-2mm} 
        \noindent
        \rule{\columnwidth-6mm}{.2mm}  
    \end{adjustwidth}%
    }
```